# Sending private file by email in android

Tags: android

I want to send a text file in an email letter.
But the thing is that I want this file to be private for my application, and I want to give read permission only for the email app.

So, i use code:

for getting file path:

logFilePath = activity.getDir("my_logs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) + "/log.txt";

for adding file to the email:

```
Uri logUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(logFilePath));
            mail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, logUri);
            mail.setType("text/plain");
```

The file is created, I can see that it is attached to the letter, when I send it, but when I receive the letter there is no attachment.

I tried this options:

```
mail.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

activity.grantUriPermission("com.google.android.gm", logUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

But the result is the same. I tried to

```
mail.setData(logUri);
```

Because I thought that may be the intent world read flag affects only the Data field, but the result was the same.

Then I tried to change the directory permission:

```
activity.getDir("my_logs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE) + "/log.txt";
```

But it gave no effect.

The

```
activity.getCacheDir() + "/log.txt";
```

is not working too.

The only option that is working is

```
activity.getExternalCacheDir() + "/log.txt";
```

So, as I can see, the file in the internal memory is not readable for the email application no matter how I try.

Is there a way to make it readable?

Or may be there is a way to make private directory/file in the external memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use a content provider in that case. There is a pre-defined content provider for sharing files, very easy to implement: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html